# Rewrite a Wordpress URL on .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, wordpress

I'm using this permalink structure on my wordpress site:

```
example.com/2011/09/mypost
```

and I'm using `RewriteRule` to visit another site on `.htaccess`,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/visit visit-site.php?siteurl=$3 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

so I can visit the site with this link

```
example.com/2011/09/mypost/visit
```

sometime I want to change my permalink with structure like `example.com/item/mypost` when I can visit another site with `example.com/item/mypost/visit`, please help me to change the `.htaccess` code above so I can access with `example.com/item/mypost/visit` link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/visit visit-site.php?siteurl=$3 [NC]
    RewriteRule item/(.*)/visit visit-site.php?siteurl=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```