# How to change WordPress intranet URL

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration, wordpress, cms

I want to change the WordPress URL of an intranet ,which is just a plain IP address, into something like: intranet.regalcouch.com. So that my users only have to type an address instead of the IP address.

I have tried to add a few lines of code by editing the **wp-config.php** file on my Debian VM but that resulted in making the WP dashboard unreachable.

So is there something that I could be doing wrong or that I am missing out on?

**Which things I have edited and what the results were:**

- Editing the Site and WordPress URL into intranet.regalcouch.com, that resulted in an unreachable intranet
- Hardcoding the original URL back into wp-config.php which worked but resulted in URL's looking like this:
  .../wordpress/index.php/index.php/ instead of .../wordpress/index.php
- Tried to change the .htaccess file with the values provided by
  WordPress but did not solved the index.php

**My configuration is as follows:**

-Debian 8 VM hosted within an ESXi environment

-Running PHP 5.6.29-0deb8ul (cli)

-Running Apache 2.4.10 (Debian)
-Running WordPress 4.7.2

WordPress has been installed as described here: http://www.linuxserve.com/2015/05/install-latest-wordpress-version-on.html

**These are the resources that I have used:**

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL
- [Rewrite a Wordpress URL on .htaccess](https://serverfault.com/questions/332843/rewrite-a-wordpress-url-on-htaccess)
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324260/how-to-configure-dns-records-for-your-web-site-in-windows-server-2003

Comment: How does your configuration look like and what kind of changes have you done exactly?

Comment: I have added more information to the description and also included the changes I made.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your client /etc/hosts file or your DNS server is correctly set up for resolution, you may want to check that the IP address is not hardcoded into some of WordPress table entries. If so, you would have to make the change manually.

I remember having had a similar problem during a migration, but unfortunately I do not have access to a test installation to replicate the scenario.

(I feel this answer should have been properly placed as a comment, but I lack the required reputation)

Comment: There are IP addresses hardcoded in certain tables to link them to the correct webpages. Does changing those URLs mitigate my problem of having an unreachable dashboard? (Given that I change the Site and WordPress URL)

Comment: Did you also try to regenerate the permalinks?

Comment: I have tried that and it makes my webpages unreachable, even when I try to edit the URL from .../index.php/index.php/picturebook to .../index.php/picturebook. Reverting the changes makes everything working again.